# How to align a picture below a <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I have used a  tag for choices to pick authors, once a author is selected, it will display an image corresponding to the Author's name, but it shows image right next to the selection instead of below.

```
<img src="" id="authorImage" width="300px" height="300px" align="top"/>
```

I've used align="top", but that doesn't work

```js
var getAuthor =  document.getElementById("authorImage");

function myAuthor(AuthorIndex)
{
  getAuthor.style.display="";
  if (AuthorIndex == 1) 
  {
    getAuthor.src = "Stephen.jpg";
    getAuthor.style.width = "300px";
    getAuthor.style.height = "300px";

  }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectAuthor" onchange="myAuthor(this.value)">
  <option value="0" onclick="">Please select an Author</option>
  <option value="1">Stephen King</option>
  <option value="2">George R. R. Martin</option>
  <option value="3">Mark Twain</option>
</select>

<img src="" id="authorImage" width="300px" height="300px" align="top"/>
```

I want the image to show below the  tag, but it show next to the . How do i fix it?

Comment: have you tried inserting `<br>` between `<select>` and `<img>` tags

Comment: Yea, this works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set display:block for image

```
img {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```js
var getAuthor =  document.getElementById("authorImage");

        function myAuthor(AuthorIndex)
        {
            getAuthor.style.display="";
            if (AuthorIndex == 1) 
            {
                getAuthor.src = "Stephen.jpg";
                getAuthor.style.width = "300px";
                getAuthor.style.height = "300px";

            }

}
```

```css
img {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectAuthor" onchange="myAuthor(this.value)">
                <option value="0" onclick="">Please select an Author</option>
                <option value="1">Stephen King</option>
                <option value="2">George R. R. Martin</option>
                <option value="3">Mark Twain</option>
        </select>

        <img src="" id="authorImage" width="300px" height="300px" align="top"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. With `<br/>`:

```js
var getAuthor =  document.getElementById("authorImage");

function myAuthor(AuthorIndex)
{
  getAuthor.style.display="";
  if (AuthorIndex == 1) 
  {
    getAuthor.src = "Stephen.jpg";
    getAuthor.style.width = "300px";
    getAuthor.style.height = "300px";

  }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectAuthor" onchange="myAuthor(this.value)">
  <option value="0" onclick="">Please select an Author</option>
  <option value="1">Stephen King</option>
  <option value="2">George R. R. Martin</option>
  <option value="3">Mark Twain</option>
</select>

<br/>

<img src="" id="authorImage" width="300px" height="300px" align="top"/>
```

2. Wrap elements in a container no with equal width of image:

```js
var getAuthor =  document.getElementById("authorImage");

function myAuthor(AuthorIndex)
{
  getAuthor.style.display="";
  if (AuthorIndex == 1) 
  {
    getAuthor.src = "Stephen.jpg";
    getAuthor.style.width = "300px";
    getAuthor.style.height = "300px";

  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select id="selectAuthor" onchange="myAuthor(this.value)">
    <option value="0" onclick="">Please select an Author</option>
    <option value="1">Stephen King</option>
    <option value="2">George R. R. Martin</option>
    <option value="3">Mark Twain</option>
  </select>

  <img src="" id="authorImage" width="300px" height="300px" align="top"/>

</div>
```

3. Give image `display: block` property:

```js
var getAuthor =  document.getElementById("authorImage");

function myAuthor(AuthorIndex)
{
  getAuthor.style.display="";
  if (AuthorIndex == 1) 
  {
    getAuthor.src = "Stephen.jpg";
    getAuthor.style.width = "300px";
    getAuthor.style.height = "300px";

  }
}
```

```css
img { display: block; }
```

```html
<select id="selectAuthor" onchange="myAuthor(this.value)">
  <option value="0" onclick="">Please select an Author</option>
  <option value="1">Stephen King</option>
  <option value="2">George R. R. Martin</option>
  <option value="3">Mark Twain</option>
</select>

<img src="" id="authorImage" width="300px" height="300px" align="top"/>
```